# CListCtrl set font style to bold

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I want to change font of any cell of CListCtrl control to bold. Can any one tell how to do it for CList Ctrl.

I have already done this for a CTreeCtrl, like this

```
pTC->SetItemState(hItemCur, TVIS_BOLD, TVIS_BOLD);
```

do we have something similar for CListCtrl?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC: How to change color/boldness of inidividual rows of ListCtrl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822657/mfc-how-to-change-color-boldness-of-inidividual-rows-of-listctrl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [CMFCListCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb983191.aspx) (VS2008 SP1 and up), you can derive a class from it and override [OnGetCellFont](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb982840.aspx). From there you return your bold font (you can create your own or return AFX_GLOBAL_DATA::fontBold):

```
HFONT CMyListCtrl::OnGetCellFont( int nRow, int nColumn, DWORD dwData /*= 0*/ )
{
    if (UseBoldFont(/* params */))
    {
        return GetGlobalData()->fontBold;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

If you have to stick to plain old CListCtrl, the easiest way would be to use Custom Draw, where you can tweak the drawing process to your own needs. Don't confuse it with Owner Draw, where you have to do *all* the drawing yourself.

[Here's an article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79/Neat-Stuff-to-Do-in-List-Controls-Using-Custom-Dra) explaining the basics of using Custom Draw with CListCtrl.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, OnCustomdraw)
```

to your message map.

Now you can simply modify items as you wish in this function. In here you can change the align, font, background-color, text-color, [...], and you can set items to bold -> [example](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?317419-Changing-font-on-my-CTreeCtrl-%96-item). The best way IMO, is to either store a pointer to a struct, class or simply a flag in the LPARAM of the item(s) in the control. This function works for both CListCtrl and CTreeCtrl.
Here is an example with flags:

```
enum ColorFlags
{
    F_COLOR_BLACK = 0x1,
    F_COLOR_WHITE = 0x2
    //and more...
};

enum CustomColors
{
    COLOR_BLACK = RGB(0, 0, 0),
    COLOR_WHITE = RGB(255, 255, 255)
};

afx_msg
void CMyListCtrl::OnCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW *pDraw = reinterpret_cast<NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*>(pNMHDR);
    switch (pDraw->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
            *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW; //Do not forget this...
            break;
        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
        {
            switch (pDraw->nmcd.lItemlParam) //Extract color from flags
            {
                case F_COLOR_BLACK:
                {
                    pDraw->clrText = COLOR_BLACK;
                } break;
                case F_COLOR_WHITE:
                {
                    pDraw->clrText = COLOR_WHITE;
                } break;
                default:
                    break;
            } //switch
        } break;
    } //switch
}
```